# Is there any implementation of Python2 where ordering is transitive?

Tags: python, sorting, python-2.x, transitivity, strict-weak-ordering

Is there any existing implementation of Python2 where ordering is [transitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation)?  That is, where it's impossible to see this behaviour without creating user-defined types:

```
>>> x < y < z < x
True
```

CPython is not transitive because of this counterexample

```
x = 'b'
y = ()
z = u'ab'
```

However, this ordering in CPython is [documented](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons) as only an implementation detail.

Comment: PyPy and Jython work like CPython for that particular example, but IronPython doesn't.

Comment: @Blender: pypy 5.4.1, `x < y < z < x` gives True for OP's example.

Comment: @kennytm: That's what I meant

Comment: @Blender I see.

Comment: I love questions like these, makes you think. Also Python3 changed to not work, need to go dig up the change log to find out why.

Comment: @Blender How does IronPython order different types?

Comment: @wim: No idea, I don't know much about it. It just doesn't outright fail on the first test like the other two implementations, so it might be work investigating.

Comment: @wim: IronPython fails as well: `2**200 < float('+inf') < [] < 2**200`

Comment: `x < y < z < x` doesn't make it a transitivity counterexample. `x < y < z and not x < z` does.

Comment: @StefanPochmann: Python's spec guarantees antisymmetry. If `x < y < z < x` holds and your relation is also transitive, then you get both `x < z` and `z < x`, which violates antisymmetry.

Comment: @StefanPochmann  Well, however you want to state it.  The example that's given in the question does also demonstrate `x < y < z and not x < z`.

Comment: @wim: I doubt that there is an implementation. Most use some sort of performance hack to compare heterogenous objects, like comparing their internal hashes, and that can be abused to get weird comparisons. You could deliberately design a Python implementation where things work as you'd expect, but that'd have to be a conscious effort. All of the major implementations have already been ruled out, so you could check the few remaining ones and probably use the same techniques to get them to misbehave.

Comment: @Blender Hmm, where does Python's spec guarantee antisymmetry? I skimmed some documentation but didn't find it. In any case, I think it's much clearer to directly use the definition of transitivity instead of relying on additional information/thinking.

Comment: @wim Do you need this for something, or are you just curious?

Comment: I'm just curious.  I will accept an answer that a) derives from the language reference directly that preservation of transitivity is impossible in python 2.x, or failing that b) can demonstrate a counterexample in each of the mainstream implementations and a convincing argument for why it's not preservable.

Comment: @StefanPochmann: it's not really explicitly written: *Objects of different types, except different numeric types and different string types, never compare equal; such objects are ordered consistently but arbitrarily*.

Comment: @Blender I don't see how you get antisymmetry from that.

Comment: @StefanPochmann: They're ordered consistently, so exactly one of `a < b` or `b < a` must hold for unequal `a` and `b`.

Comment: I'd have thought 'consistency' in this context refers to repeatability, not mathematical consistency

Comment: @Blender The term *consistently* in that context could also means that "objects of type X are all `<` to object of type Y", i.e. when the types are different and the types are not both numeric/strings, then the order of the values is defined by the order of just their types. This is even stronger than antisymmetry because it tells you that if `a < b -> forall x, y, type(x)=type(a), type(y) = type(b) -> x < y`.

Comment: In any case: thank God python3 changed this to be: if you compare two different types that are not numeric/strings then `TypeError`!

Comment: @wim: What's the difference between the two interpretations?

Comment: @Blender  As an example, an object which override `__lt__` to return True and also `__gt__` to return True, it would be inconsistent mathematically (because he claims to be both bigger and smaller than 0), but one might call it 'consistent' in another sense because it is consistently wrong - the behaviour is always the same across e.g. different interpreters and platforms.  'Consistent' as 'deterministic', 'predictable'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every mainstream Python implementation fails in one way or another except for Skulpt, but it's arguably an incomplete implementation.

**CPython (and variants), PyPy, and Jython**:

```
>>> 'b' < () < u'ab' < 'b'
True
```

**IronPython**:

IronPython internally compares the .NET `Object.GetHashCode()` hashes of unlike objects, so you can break it by abusing the special handling of `int` and `float` comparisons and the fact that the internal hash representation of `float('+inf')` is less than the hash of `[]` (I'm not sure how stable this is, so it might not work on every installation of IronPython):

```
>>> 2**200 < float('+inf') < [] < 2**200
True
```

**[CLPython](https://common-lisp.net/project/clpython/)**

```
>>> {1: 3} < {1: 4} < {1: 3}
1
>>> {1: 3} < {1: 3}
0
```

**Skulpt**

If you count [Skulpt](http://www.skulpt.org/) as a complete implementation of Python 2 (it can't compare dictionaries and a few other inconvenient types, and has no `unicode` type), it actually does work by copying CPython's rules for comparison and conveniently leaving out the `unicode` type:

```
# 1. None is less than anything
# 2. Sequence types are greater than numeric types
# 3. [d]ict < [l]ist < [s]tring < [t]uple

>>> None < 0 < {} < [] < '' < ()
True
```

For CPython 2, you would actually have `[t]uple < [u]nicode`, but because `unicode` and `str` comparisons are handled as a special case, you lose transitivity. Although it's unlikely that Python 2 will get a patch to fix this "bug", I think you can ensure transitivity by just explicitly changing the order from:

```
[d]ict < [l]ist < [s]tring < [t]uple < [u]nicode
```

To:

```
[u]nicode < [d]ict < [l]ist < [s]tring < [t]uple
```

That way, the special case of `str` to `unicode` comparisons doesn't break anything.

Comment: I just tried that in Skulpt and it worked fine, gave me `False`. What spec does `{1: 3} < {1: 4} < {1: 3}` holding violate?

Comment: @StefanPochmann: `{1: 3} < {1: 4}` and `{1: 4} < {1: 3}` can't both be true, since this would make sorting unstable.

Comment: How does `{1: 3} < {1: 4} < {1: 3}` violate the Python specs and `'b' < () < u'ab' < 'b'` doesn't? Or you mean they are both violations?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ: Python only cares about sorting being stable, string comparisons making sense, and numeric comparisons making sense. The first one makes sorting unstable, since `{1: 3} < {1: 4}` and `{1: 4} < {1: 3}` can't both hold. `'b' < () < u'ab' < 'b'` doesn't violate anything, since sorting those four elements is stable and strings are compared lexicographically.

Comment: Total ordering is not implemented also in CPython 2.7 for `set`:  
`>>> sorted([set([1]), set([0]), set([1])])`  
result `[set([1]), set([0]), set([1])]`. Both inequalities are False if one set is not a subset of other. In Python 3 it is said explicitly that total ordering is not applied to sets or mappings.

Comment: @hynekcer: Could you point me to where ordering is described for mappings in the spec?

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to be ordered `'b' , () , u'ab'` in some case and `() , u'ab' , 'b'` in another?

Comment: `sorted(['b' , () , u'ab'])` and `sorted([() , u'ab' , 'b'])` have different results (leaving both the lists unchanged). Isn't this a failure/violation?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ: The sorting is stable (as in, it always produces the same output for the same input), but since the set isn't totally ordered, there are multiple ways to sort it. I don't think it does.

Comment: I know (that the sort is stable). Is there somewhere in the Python specs that states that the order is not (or may not be) transitive? The problem _ as I see it - is that if the transitive property does not hold (which obviously doesn't in the implementations shown), then it is not even a partial order. (not that matter much for actual use, I don't think it's sane to compare different types)

Comment: Thinking again, "stable" means something else for sorting algorithms. It has a point when the sorted objects have attached properties that are not used for the ordering. You are using the term differently.

Comment: @Blender: I started to write an answer because I have much information.

Answer (score 2):

Some comparisons are **declared as not specified** in Python 2.7:

The most important general rules for comparisons are in
[The Python Language Reference](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/index.html) chapter 5. Expressions / 5.9 [Comparisons](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#comparisons).

The first rules are the well known ones for comparison of numeric types (bool, int, long, float), strings (str, unicode), tuples and lists. The last two rules declare what is not specified:

> - Mappings (dictionaries) compare equal if and only if their sorted (key, value) lists compare equal. [5] Outcomes other than equality are resolved consistently, but are **not otherwise defined**. [6]
> - Most other objects of built-in types compare unequal unless they are the same object; the choice whether one object is considered smaller or larger than another one is made **arbitrarily** but **consistently within one execution** of a program.

Many specific rules are in *Comparison* chapter in *The Python Standard Library* / *Built-in Types*, referenced above in the question, and in docs about specific types like *complex*, *Decimal* or *Fraction*.

Order comparison is not supported for type *complex* and it should raise TypeError. *Decimal* type is compared by value. It is compatible with *numbers.Number* since Python 2.7. *fractions.Fraction* is also compared by value.

---

My reflection: If a relation of comparison can be *arbitrary* and can be not reproducible within two executions of the program on the same computer, then it is not useful to say about transitivity. All cases above where the order is explicitly not specified in Python 2 should raise TypeError in Python 3.

The transitivity or ordering of builtin types is known broken in Python 2.7 only between types where equivalency of values of different builtin types is implemented but they are not implemented equivalent to other types.

Example: broken transitivity in *IronPython* (inspired by Blender's comment and simplified):

```
>>> assert long(0) < 1.0 < [] < long(0)  # 0 < 1; 'float' < 'list' < 'long'
```

---

Even the equivalency (`==`), that looks simpler to decide, is also **not** always transitive. That breaks the transitivity of the operator (`<=`). See examples in comments. (Thanks for fix) (Equivalency is not the identity. `a is b` implies `a == b`, but not vice-versa.)

Examples use many trivial user-defined classes, with names one-letter capital or lowercase:

```
class A(object): pass

class a(object): pass
...

class z(object): pass
```

#### Observation - Numbers

All numeric types have many naturally equivalent values in CPython and IronPython (and probably in all other implementations according docs)

```
>>>  assert (False == 0 == 0L == 0.0 == 0 + 0j == Decimal('0') == Fraction(0, 1) <
...          True == 1 == 1L == 1.0 == 1 + 0j == Decimal('1') == Fraction(1, 1))
```

Numeric types are ordered before all other types in CPython:

```
>>> assert 0 < 10**1000 < float('inf') < A() < Z() < a()
```

Numeric types are dispersed between other types in IronPython

```
>>> assert D() < decimal.Decimal('0') < E()
>>> assert F() < fractions.Fraction(0, 1) < G()
>>> assert b() < False < c()   # bool
>>> assert c() < 0 + 0j < d()  # complex
>>> assert f() < 0.0 < g()     # float
>>> assert i() < 0 < j()       # int
>>> assert l() < 0L < m()      # long
```

#### Strings etc

str, bytearray and unicode have equivalent values

```
>>> assert bytearray('ab') == 'ab' == u'ab'
```

Nothing special in ordering to other types is used in CPython,

```
>>> assert b() < bytearray('ab') < c()  # bytearray
>>> assert s() < 'ab' < t()             # str
>>> assert u() < u'ab' < v()            # unicode in CPython
```

In IronPython: The type `unicode` behaves like `str`. It is not strange because strings are implemented in .NET like unicode and the same is in IronPython.

```
 >>> assert s() < u'ab' < t()           # unicode in Iron Python like str
 >>> unicode
 <type 'str'>
```

Comment: You're wrong about `==` always being transitive, since `bytearray('ab') == 'ab' == u'ab'` is true but `bytearray('ab') == u'ab'` is false (at least in CPython).

Comment: And `OrderedDict([(0,0), (1,1)]) == {0:0, 1:1} == OrderedDict([(1,1), (0,0)])`  provides another counterexample of equality transitivity.

Comment: @StefanPochmann, @vim: Thanks. Fixed. That are great counterexamples for a possible reflection about trantitivity of `<=` operator.

Comment: Do you have a doc reference for "Numeric types are ordered before all other types in CPython" ?

Comment: @vim No. It is a conclusion of tests in the part *observation*. I think that less important features are not documented in order to allow different implementations like IronPython. The docs for Python 2 is only for 2.7, where many details of deprecated methods are intentionally omitted, e.g `coerce(...)`, `__cmp__(...)`. The method `__cmp__` is still crucial for comparison for many types in Python 2.7. Many types with total ordering (e.g. int, dict) don't implement `__eq__`, `__lt__`... and implement only `__cmp__`.

Comment: Some types with partial ordering (like OrderedDict) allow that two objects don't have either order: not less, not greater but also not equal. This is if two OrderedDict have the same sorted(x.items()) and only the order of keys is different.  It is implemented by only three methods `__cmp__`, `__eq__`, `__ne__`. It is enough to denote the strange result of comparison.